# undefined method `each_slice' for 0:Integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Please i implemented a code in my view file and i am getting an error that i have no idea.

> undefined method `each_slice' for 0:Integer

And the error highlights this snippet

```
- @standups.each_slice[3] do |standups|
```

> the view

```
content-header
  h2 My Activity
.content
  - @standups.each_slice[3] do |standups|
    .row
      - standups.each do |standup|
       -cache standup do
          .col-sm-4
            .box.box-primary
........
```

Comment: What is in `@xtandups`, looks like it is an Integer not an Array (or other Enumerable)

Comment: @Kris Yes its some enumerable

Comment: @bottles: no, it's not. Evidently.

Comment: Also, there's problem of square brackets, but you'll get to it later.

Comment: Do `@standups.inspect` to see what it is.

Comment: show us the code where you do ´@standups = xxx´, also square brackets are wrong.

Comment: @standups.inspect returned nil

Comment: @standups =  current_user.standups                    .includes(:dids, :todos, :   blockers)                    .references(:tasks).order('standup_date   DESC').page(1).total_pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller you want to only to the query: `@standups = current_user.standups.includes(:dids, :todos, :blockers).references(:tasks).order('standup_date DESC')`.

Currently you are doing the query, getting the result, and assigning the count of results to the @standups variable. This is causing the error.

It looks like you are using the kaminari gem to do pagination. If so you can still do that by adding it to the query (I split out out into multiple lines to be a little more readable):

```
def index
    ... # other code
    @standups = current_user.standups
    @standups = @standups.includes(:dids, :todos, :blockers).references(:tasks).order('standup_date DESC')
    @standups = @standups.page params[:page] # kaminari pagination
end
```

And in your view, you can show the total pages and your pagination:

```
content-header
    h2 My Activity
.content
    div #{@standups.total_pages} Pages
    - @standups.each_slice(3) do |standups|
        .row
            ... 
= paginate @standups
```

Comment: i can never thank you much.This did the magic. Thanks to everyone.

Comment: `each_slice` takes an argument e.g. `each_slice(3)` whereas `each_slice[3]` will raise an `ArgumentError`